# HQL sorting records by using greatest of 2 columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

For each row in my database, I have 2 columns, say `id` and `A`. Sometimes `A` can be  `null`. I want to sort all records by greatest of its `id` and `A` value, but if `A` is `null`, it will be ignored and the column will be sorted by `id` instead.

I'm using Hibernate and database as MySQL. So far, my HQL is like

```
select i from Item as i order by GREATEST(id, a)
```

it is working fine except for the records with `A=null`. For those values, they appear at the end of the returning results (they're supposed to be sorted using their `id` as key).

How to write such an HQL statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody solved it with `Case..When..End`, works perfectly.

```
select i from Item as i order by CASE WHEN a = null THEN id ELSE GREATEST(id, a) END DESC
```